# Alpine.js +flatpickr Datetimepicker is not working

Tags: javascript, python, axios, flatpickr, alpine.js

i really stucked in my project. I have a site with alpine.js where i want to render data to an element

Everything is working perfect until the fact that my flatpickr is not shown up.
The datepicker is working perfect. It seams, that x-html, x-text nor document.getElementById().innerHTML used in alpine.js is working ....

```
<div x-data="app()" x-html="modalData" x-show="isOpenModal" id="test">
 only a test
  <input class="picker" />
</div>
```

......

```
    <script>
      const fp = flatpickr(".picker", {
        locale: "at", 
        minDate: "1930-01",
        maxDate: 'today',
        enableTime: true,
        time_24hr: true,
        minTime: "07:00",
        maxTime: "20:00",
        dateFormat: "d.m.Y H:i",
        disableMobile: "true",
        static:false,
              });

     function app(){  
        return {
            isOpenModal: true,
            modalData: '<input class=" form-control placeholder-primary-500 picker">',
            }
        }
```

in this very simple example 2 input field are shown up, but only the second shows the flatpickr.

Try:

- If i delete the second the first will be not working.
- x-text instead of x-html brings only the text <input ..... >
- on the other hand without alpine.js it is working

```
<script>
 const test = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '<input class="picker" />';
 const fp = flatpickr(".picker", {
            locale: "at",
            minDate: "1930-01",
            maxDate: 'today',
            enableTime: true,
            time_24hr: true,
            minTime: "07:00",
            maxTime: "20:00",
            dateFormat: "d.m.Y H:i",
            disableMobile: "true",
            static:false,
      });
 </script>
```

UPDATE 30.10.20:
I simplified the code, is still not working but why ?

```
<div x-data="test()">
 <button  @click="show = true"> Klick </button>
    <div  x-show="show" x-model="daten" x-html="daten"> 
 <input class="bg-green-500 picker" />
</div>
```

it is shown up correctly, flatpickr is initialized but the picker is not shown up.

```
    function test() {
    return {
        daten:'<input class="bg-red-500 picker" />',
        show: false,
    }
}
```

such a simple code and not working :(
I hope you understand my confusing special problem.

Thanks for helping,

Greets Martin

Comment: it seems to be a timing problem. when alpine.js update the variable, flatpickr is not shown up, but when the class is defined before alpine.js is rendering it is working. But that's a big problem because i want a form generated by my backend an get the data with axios. so i really need, that flatpickr and alpine.js can handle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is initializing the `flatpickr`. if you add it on the `init` hook of the alphine component it works perfectly. so when alphine component initializes the code segment in `init` hook will be executed.
So to solve your issue,

```html
 <div x-data="app()" x-init="initFlatpickr">
       <input x-ref="picker" />
 </div>
```

and in the script tag,

```html
<script> 
     function app() {
            return {
                initFlatpickr() {
                    const fp = flatpickr(this.$refs.picker, {
                        locale: "at",
                        minDate: "1930-01",
                        maxDate: "today",
                        enableTime: true,
                        time_24hr: true,
                        minTime: "07:00",
                        maxTime: "20:00",
                        dateFormat: "d.m.Y H:i",
                        disableMobile: "true",
                        static: false,
                    });
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

Now the `initFlatpickr` function will execute when the alphine js component is initialized.
I have made use of `refs` which is a helpful alternative to setting ids and using `document.querySelector` all over the place.
check out the [docs](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine#x-ref) for more detail.

Comment: thank you, but this was not the mistake in my case. I really understand you and i like the answer. The mistake is the x-html from alpine.js I get a generated form from the backend server and i want to put it in a modal and there the picker should work. The problem of your solution is, that the picker would be initialized bevor the form comes back from the server.... My solution is now is instead of x-html i use "document.getElementById('modalContent').innerHTML = this.modalData" when the answer comes from the server. But thank you!!