# proper usage of flatpickr and laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, flatpickr

Hello all I am trying to get Flatpickr working with Laravel v8.

I've done the following:

```
npm install flatpickr
```

then I added to the resources/app.js:

```js
const flatpickr = require("flatpickr");

flatpickr("#myField", {});
```

in my view I have this defined:

```html
<input id="myField" type="text" name="myField" value="2021-01-16 15:18:02">
```

But I get the following errors:

```
app.js:23902 Uncaught TypeError: flatpickr is not a function
    at Object../resources/js/app.js (app.js:23902)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.0 (app.js:23945)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at app.js:84
    at app.js:87
```

I have no Ideas, how to proceed, tbh.

Comment: One workaround is for me, currently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64597995/alpine-js-flatpickr-datetimepicker-is-not-working with cdn import. But with the npm install import I am still strugeling

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution:

after npm install I had to add to the resources/js/app.js

```
require('flatpickr')
```

and in my resources/css/app.css I had to add:

```
@import('flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css')
```

after npm run dev I had the stuff available in my application.

To use it then I sticked to another post @stackoverflow :

[Alpine.js +flatpickr Datetimepicker is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64597995/alpine-js-flatpickr-datetimepicker-is-not-working)

was then my final solution.

Done this with Laravel 8

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something different.

```
npm install flatpickr
```

Include JS Code

```
// resources/js/bootstrap.js
const flatpickr = require('flatpickr');
```

Include CSS Code

```
//resources/css/app.css
@import 'flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css';
```

Rebuild

```
npm run dev
```

Use somewhere in my app. (YMMV)

```
<div wire:ignore>
<input
    wire:model.lazy="birthday"
    x-data
    x-init="flatpickr($refs.input, {dateFormat:'m/d/Y'} );"
    x-ref="input"
    type="text"
    class="max-w-lg block w-full shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:max-w-xs sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md"
    />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Jim's answer is correct! my job;

npm install flatpickr

// resources/js/bootstrap.js

const flatpickr = require('flatpickr');

//resources/css/app.css

@import 'flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css';

npm run dev

let flatpickrInstance
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#save_memory").click(function(event) {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Please enter departure date',
                    html: '',
                    stopKeydownPropagation: false,
                    preConfirm: () => {
                        if (flatpickrInstance.selectedDates[0]  {
                        flatpickrInstance = flatpickr(
                            Swal.getPopup().querySelector('#expiry-date')
                        )
                    }
                })
            });
        });

Comment: duplicated answer in this thread. No need to post